# Give users full permissions to: C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer

Tags: active-directory, windows-server, group-policy

Hihi, through group policy, I am trying to give users access to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer" on their local machine.

These users are in the OU "Colleagues" and a part of a security group called "Colleagues".

I have done the following steps but it does not seem to work:

- Open the Group Policy Management Console on your domain controller.
- Navigate to the Group Policy Object (GPO) that is linked to the "Colleagues" OU.
- Right-click on the GPO and select "Edit" to open the Group Policy Management Editor.
- In the editor, go to "User Configuration" -> "Policies" -> "Windows Settings" -> "Security Settings" -> "File System".
- Right-click on "File System" and select "Add File".
- In the "Add a file or folder" dialog, enter the path "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer".
- Click "OK" to close the dialog.
- In the "Add Object" dialog, select the "Colleagues" security group from the "Group or user names" section.
- In the "Permissions for Colleagues" section, check the "Allow" box for the "Read & execute" and "Read" permissions.
- Click "OK" to save the changes.
- Checked the boxes "Configure this file or folder then" "Replace existing permissions on all subfolders and files with inheritable permissions"
- Close the Group Policy Management Editor.

The users still require admin permission to make changes to these files. What have I done wrong?

Thank you in advance.